# Keras fit_generator takes image size as batch_size

Tags: python, keras, generator

I'm trying to train my implementation of enet on the tusimple benchmark. For 
this task I have written a generator (inheriting from keras.utils.Sequence).

But when I start training the model keras always takes the height of the image as the batch size.

I have already written a similair generator for other datasets and didn#t have this problem, even though the output dims of both are the same.

**edit** : I found some errors in my generator code and fixed them, but their still in the code below, however they dont affect the problem with the batch size

```
import tensorflow as tf
import json
import numpy as np
import cv2
class tusimple_gen(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, batch_size,shape=(720,1280), filepath='../culane/', start=0, end=1):
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.filepath = filepath

        self.json = [json.loads(line) for line in open(self.filepath+'label_data_0313.json')]

        s = int(start*len(self.json))
        e = int(end*len(self.json))
        self.json = self.json[s:e]
        self.shape = shape

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.json) // self.batch_size


    def get_item(self, idx):
        gt = self.json[idx]
        gt_lanes = gt['lanes']
        y_samples = gt['h_samples']
        raw_file = self.filepath + gt['raw_file']

        x = cv2.imread(raw_file, -1)
        x = x/255

        gt_lanes_vis = [[(x,y) for (x,y) in zip(lane,y_samples) if x>=0] for lane in gt_lanes]
        y = np.zeros((x.shape[0],x.shape[1],5))
        y_5 = np.ones((x.shape[0],x.shape[1]))
        y[:,:,4] = y_5

        for i,lane in enumerate(gt_lanes_vis):            
            lane_im = cv2.polylines(np.zeros_like(y[:,:,0]), np.int32([lane]), isClosed=False, color=(255,255,255), thickness=10)
            y[:,:,i] = lane_im
            y[:,:,4] = y[:,:,4] - lane_im




        if self.shape[:2] != x.shape[:2]:
            x = cv2.resize(x,(self.shape[1],self.shape[0] ))
            y = cv2.resize(y,(self.shape[1],self.shape[0] ))

        return (x,y)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        x_ret = np.zeros((self.batch_size, self.shape[0],self.shape[1],3))
        y_ret = np.zeros((self.batch_size, self.shape[0],self.shape[1],5))

        for i in range(self.batch_size):
            x,y = self.get_item(i)
            x_ret[i,:,:,:] = x
            y_ret[i,:,:,:] = y

        return (x_ret,y_ret)
```

The actual training code:

```
WIDTH = 1280//2
HEIGHT = 720//2

gen_train = tusimple_gen(batch_size=1,shape=(HEIGHT,WIDTH),start=0,end=0.8)
gen_val = tusimple_gen(batch_size=1,shape=(HEIGHT,WIDTH),start=0.8,end=1)

training_history = model.fit_generator(
                    generator=gen_train,
                    epochs=40,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=gen_val,
                    validation_steps=len(gen_val),
                    callbacks=[tensorboard_callback],
                    shuffle=True
                   )
```

The output of fit_generator()

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model failed to serialize as JSON. Ignoring... Layers with arguments in `__init__` must override `get_config`.
Epoch 1/40
 31/360 [=>............................] - ETA: 1:47 - loss: -111.2384 - acc: 0.9998 - dice_coef: 0.9694 - iou_loss_core: 0.9380
```

Comment: What about the model? Can you provide the code?

Comment: If it's not a Keras's bug then problem might be there

Comment: Anyway how do you know that it's use img_size as batch_size?

Comment: You might have 450 samples in total from which you are using 80% (=360) samples for training and remaining 90 samples for validation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NotImplementedError: Layers with arguments in \`\_\_init\_\_\` must override \`get\_config\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58678836/notimplementederror-layers-with-arguments-in-init-must-override-get-conf)