# NotImplementedError: Layers with arguments in `__init__` must override `get_config`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to save my TensorFlow model using `model.save()`, however - I am getting this error.

The model summary is provided here:
[Model Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkrR1.png)

The code for the transformer model:

```py
def transformer(vocab_size, num_layers, units, d_model, num_heads, dropout, name="transformer"):
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,), name="inputs")
    dec_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,), name="dec_inputs")

    enc_padding_mask = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
        create_padding_mask, output_shape=(1, 1, None),
        name='enc_padding_mask')(inputs)
    # mask the future tokens for decoder inputs at the 1st attention block
    look_ahead_mask = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
        create_look_ahead_mask,
        output_shape=(1, None, None),
        name='look_ahead_mask')(dec_inputs)
    # mask the encoder outputs for the 2nd attention block
    dec_padding_mask = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
        create_padding_mask, output_shape=(1, 1, None),
        name='dec_padding_mask')(inputs)

    enc_outputs = encoder(
        vocab_size=vocab_size,
        num_layers=num_layers,
        units=units,
        d_model=d_model,
        num_heads=num_heads,
        dropout=dropout,
    )(inputs=[inputs, enc_padding_mask])

    dec_outputs = decoder(
        vocab_size=vocab_size,
        num_layers=num_layers,
        units=units,
        d_model=d_model,
        num_heads=num_heads,
        dropout=dropout,
    )(inputs=[dec_inputs, enc_outputs, look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask])

    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=vocab_size, name="outputs")(dec_outputs)

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs, dec_inputs], outputs=outputs, name=name)
```

I don't understand why it's giving this error since the model trains perfectly fine. 
Any help would be appreciated.

My saving code for reference:

```py
print("Saving the model.")
saveloc = "C:/tmp/solar.h5"
model.save(saveloc)
print("Model saved to: " + saveloc + " succesfully.")
```

Comment: i think this has changed with tensorflow 2.2.0 .. so now you wont run into this error

Answer (score 88, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature.

This error lets you know that TF can't save your model, because it won't be able to load it.
Specifically, it won't be able to reinstantiate your custom `Layer` classes: [**`encoder`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer#encoder_layer) and [**`decoder`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer#decoder_layer).

**To solve this,** just override their [**`get_config`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#get_config) method according to the new arguments you've added.

> A layer config is a Python dictionary (serializable) containing the configuration of a layer. The same layer can be reinstantiated later (without its trained weights) from this configuration.

---

For example, if your `encoder` class looks something like this:

```
class encoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(
        self,
        vocab_size, num_layers, units, d_model, num_heads, dropout,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.units = units
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.dropout = dropout

    # Other methods etc.
```

then you only need to override this method:

```
    def get_config(self):

        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            'vocab_size': self.vocab_size,
            'num_layers': self.num_layers,
            'units': self.units,
            'd_model': self.d_model,
            'num_heads': self.num_heads,
            'dropout': self.dropout,
        })
        return config
```

When TF sees this (for both classes), you will be able to save the model.

Because now when the model is loaded, TF will be able to reinstantiate the same layer from config.

---

[**`Layer.from_config`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#from_config)'s [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L578-L594) may give a better sense of how it works:

```
@classmethod
def from_config(cls, config):
  return cls(**config)
```

Comment: I'll try this. Shouldn't this be done by default using the parameters from the class construction?

Comment: This *could* have been done, but consider the case where not all parameters need to be saved, and just their derivatives are enough. For example the `mean` and `std` of `x_train`. In that case, the layer can accept either `x_train` or `(mean, std)` to construct. When building the model you'll use `x_train` and save `self.mean, self.std`, then save only `mean, std` to `config` to reinstantiate, without the entire `x_train`.

Comment: I did not get it very well. is there any sources to read more about it? Also, why should we over write the encoder layer and not the encoder itself? Also, what if the encoder layer is a function not a class?

Comment: @Mee **1.** Yes: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#you_can_optionally_enable_serialization_on_your_layers  **2.** Because serializing standard parts of the model already works out of the box. But for custom layers like Encoder and Decoder, you need to define it.  **3.** I'm not sure, you may want to ask this as a separate question. But why not just put your function's logic into a Layer subclass?

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I did put it in a sepearte question. May you please check it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59796343/transformer-model-not-able-to-be-saved

Comment: Is this overriding `config` still needed to be done manually? I seem to be able to save my custom layer (adds arguments in __init__) with tf.saved_model but, run into warning same as the error described by op if i try to use tensorboard on it

Comment: Yes, post a new question and link to it here.

Comment: #EliaDL - Sure! Here is link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61947226/in-tensorflow-for-custom-layers-that-need-arguments-at-instantialion-does-the .. Looking forward to hearing form you there! Thank you tons in advance

Answer (score 7):

This problem is caused by mixing imports between the keras and tf.keras libraries, which is not supported.

Use tf.keras.models or usr keras.models everywhere

You should never mix imports between these libraries, as it will not work and produces all kinds of strange error messages. These errors change with versions of keras and tensorflow.

Comment: Even if my problem was not exactly the same as OP, I was getting exactly the same error. John's answer did the magic for me,  I let my VSCode auto import Dropout when I wrote: model.add(Dropout()). It imported it : from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core import Dropout and thus creating the above error. 
Proper import is : from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout

Answer (score 3):

I suggest You try the following:

```
model = tf.keras.Model(...)
model.save_weights("some_path")
...
model.load_weights("some_path")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think simple solution is to install the tensorflow==2.4.2 for gpu tensorflow-gpu==2.4.2 , i faced the issue and debug the whole day but it was not resolved. finally i installed the older stable version and error is gone

Answer (score 0):

Adding *save_format='tf'* parameter solved it for me:

```
model.save(MODEL_PATH, save_format='tf')
```

Answer (score 0):

We have 2 model save formats:

Either TensorFlow SavedModel or HDF5

1/SavedModel saves the execution graph. Thus, SavedModels are able to save custom objects like subclassed models and custom layers without requiring the original code.
If you only supply the name of the saved model, e.g. `model.save('my_model')`, then the saved model format will be TF savedmodel as default.

2/To save custom objects with HDF5 format:

You have get_config method in your object, and optionally a from_config classmethod etc. (see the documentation)
If you supply the H5 file extension, e.g. `model.save('my_model.h5')`, then the saved model format will be HDF5.

I used the first method (saved model format) and it worked for me without errors.