# TensorFlow 2.3: load model from ModelCheckPoint callback with both custom layers and model

Tags: tensorflow

I have wrote a custom code to build a UNet architecture. To do so I have firstly subclassed the tf.keras.layers.Layer object to define an encoder convolutional block composed by a conv3D layer, a BatchNormalization layer and a Activation layer, similarly I defined a decoder inverse convolutional block composed by a Conv3DTranspose layer, a BatchNormalization layer, an Activation layer and a Concatenate layer. Finally I subclassed the tf.keras.Model object to define the full model, composed by 4 enconding blocks and 4 decoding blocks.

To checkpoint the model while training I have used the tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint callback. However when a I try to load back the model (that in fact is still training) with tf.keras.models.load_model() I receive the following error: `ValueError: No model found in config file.`

Here the full code for the model definition, building and fitting:

```
import tensorflow as tf


# Encoder block
class ConvBlock(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, n_filters, conv_size, conv_stride, **kwargs):
        super(ConvBlock, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.conv3D = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(
            filters=n_filters,
            kernel_size=conv_size,
            strides=conv_stride,
            padding="same",
        )
        self.batch_norm = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.relu = tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu")

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        h = self.conv3D(inputs)
        if training:
            h = self.batch_norm(h)
        h = self.relu(h)
        return h


# Decoder block
class InvConvBlock(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, n_filters, conv_size, conv_stride, activation, **kwargs):
        super(InvConvBlock, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.conv3D_T = tf.keras.layers.Conv3DTranspose(
            filters=n_filters,
            kernel_size=conv_size,
            strides=conv_stride,
            padding="same",
        )
        self.batch_norm = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.activ = tf.keras.layers.Activation(activation)
        self.concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)

    def call(self, inputs, feat_concat=None, training=None):
        h = self.conv3D_T(inputs)
        if training:
            h = self.batch_norm(h)
        h = self.activ(h)
        if feat_concat is not None:
            h = self.concat([h, feat_concat])
        return h


class UNet(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, n_filters, e_size, e_stride, d_size, d_stride, **kwargs):
        super(UNet, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # Encoder
        self.conv_block_1 = ConvBlock(n_filters, e_size, e_stride)
        self.conv_block_2 = ConvBlock(n_filters * 2, e_size, e_stride)
        self.conv_block_3 = ConvBlock(n_filters * 4, e_size, (1, 1, 1))
        self.conv_block_4 = ConvBlock(n_filters * 8, e_size, (1, 1, 1))

        # Decoder
        self.inv_conv_block_1 = InvConvBlock(n_filters * 4, d_size, (1, 1, 1), "relu")
        self.inv_conv_block_2 = InvConvBlock(n_filters * 2, d_size, (1, 1, 1), "relu")
        self.inv_conv_block_3 = InvConvBlock(n_filters, d_size, d_stride, "relu")
        self.inv_conv_block_4 = InvConvBlock(1, d_size, d_stride, "sigmoid")

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        h1 = self.conv_block_1(inputs, **kwargs)
        h2 = self.conv_block_2(h1, **kwargs)
        h3 = self.conv_block_3(h2, **kwargs)
        h = self.conv_block_4(h3, **kwargs)

        h = self.inv_conv_block_1(h, feat_concat=h3, **kwargs)
        h = self.inv_conv_block_2(h, feat_concat=h2, **kwargs)
        h = self.inv_conv_block_3(h, feat_concat=h1, **kwargs)
        h = self.inv_conv_block_4(h, **kwargs)
        return h


model = UNet(
        n_filters,
        e_size,
        e_stride,
        d_size,
        d_stride,
)
model.build((None, *input_shape, 1))

loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate)
metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall()]

model.compile(
    loss=loss,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    metrics=metrics,
)

CP_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        f"{checkpoint_dir}/model.h5", save_freq='epoch', monitor="loss" 
)

unet.fit(
        data,
        epochs=opts.epochs,
        callbacks=[CP_callback],
)
```

To load the model I used the following code on another python console:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.load_model(f'{checkpoint_dir}/model.h5')
```

but here I receive the above mentioned error. What am I missing? Or what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you don't define the `get_config` method in your custom layers. For this check, this exited [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58799021/9215780) in SO.

Otherwise, you can save the **trained weights** (not the full model) and load the model as follows. In that case, you don't need to define this function. Please note, it's good practice to do, however. Here is a workaround for your problem:

```
# callback
tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('model.h5',
                                    monitor='val_loss',
                                    verbose= 1,
                                    save_best_only=True,
                                    mode= 'min',
                                    save_weights_only=True) # <---- only save weight

# train
model = UNet(
        n_filters,
        e_size,
        e_stride,
        d_size,
        d_stride,
)
model.compile(...)
model.fit(...)

# inference 
model = UNet(
        n_filters,
        e_size,
        e_stride,
        d_size,
        d_stride,
)
model.build((None, *input_shape, 1))
model.load_weights('model.h5')
```

For more details, see the documentation of [Serialization and saving](https://keras.io/guides/serialization_and_saving/) and also [collab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/172D4jishSgE3N7AO6U2OKAA_0wNnrMOq#scrollTo=xXgtNRCSyuIW) demonstration of François Chollet. Also, We've written an article about model subclassing and custom training stuff in `tf 2.x`, in the **Save and Load** section (at the bottom) of this article, we've demonstrated many strategies, [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/model-sub-classing-and-custom-training-loop-from-scratch-in-tensorflow-2-cc1d4f10fb4e), hope that help.

---

### Update

I've run your public colab notebook. Unfortunately, I am facing the same issue, and it's a bit weird and currently, I don't have the exact answer for saving the entire model in the `ModelCheckpoint` callback with **Custom Layer** even if we define the `get_config()` method.

However, there is another workaround that may come in handy for you. As we know there are two major ways to save `tf` models: (1). `SaveModel` and `HDF5` format. The way is we choose the `SaveMoedl` format. Which is recommended by the way and safe to use.

The key difference between `HDF5` and `SavedModel` is that `HDF5` uses object configs to save the model architecture, while `SavedModel` saves the execution graph. Thus, `SavedModels` are able to save custom objects like subclassed models and custom layers without requiring the original code.

Now, as for your requirements, you are saving the entire model along with the best `loss` or `val_loss` in training time. For that, we can define a custom callback do save the model for lowest `validation_loss` (or whatever you want). As follows:

```
class SaveModelH5(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
         self.val_loss = []
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        current_val_loss = logs.get("val_loss")
        self.val_loss.append(logs.get("val_loss"))
        if current_val_loss <= min(self.val_loss):
            print('Find lowest val_loss. Saving entire model.')
            self.model.save('unet', save_format='tf') # < ----- Here 

save_model = SaveModelH5() 
unet.fit(.., callbacks=save_model)
```

Using

```
model.save('any_name', save_format=`tf`)
```

allows us create a `any_name` working directory, inside which it contains `assets`, `saved_model.pb`, and `variables`. The model architecture and training configuration, including the optimizer, losses, and metrics are stored in saved_model.pb. The weights are saved in the variables directory.

When saving the model and its layers, the SavedModel format stores the class name, `call` function, losses, and weights (and the config, if implemented). The `call` function defines the computation graph of the model/layer. In the absence of the model/layer config, the `call` function is used to create a model that exists like the original model which can be trained, evaluated, and used for inference. When we need to re-load the saved model, we can do as follows:

```
new_unet = tf.keras.models.load_model("unet", compile=False)
```

[Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1crnBe-KvubYSFlJz8sDxOKGkguhhW2-E?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it was very helpful indeed. I was feared too that this could be the problem. However it is still not very clear to me how to define the `get_config` method. And if it should be enough to define it in the custom layers or if it is recommended to define it also in the custom model.

Comment: I am trying to do it in the recommended way, but adding the `get_config` and `from_config` methods in both the custom layers and in the custom model does not solve the issue. The `get_config` methods return a dictionary of all arguments to initialize the objects, while the `from_config(cls, config)` class methods return `cls(**config)`. Thank you

Comment: If possible please provide some reproducible code. Have you tried the above process? Train the model and save the weights (not full model) and reload the weight as mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, the workaround of saving and loading only the weights works perfectly! I am actually doing like that. Thank you. Just saving and loading the full model remain still an issue to me. I am not used to forum questioning and answering, how can I provide you a reproducible code?

Comment: Probably you're using volumetric medical data 4D). I guess this is segmentation stuff. Here is one kinda segmentation [dataset](https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/) but not 4D. Grab this dataset and use it to reproduce your issue. And make your code concise.

Comment: I've added a link for your unsolved issue (`get_config()`). Check.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1crnBe-KvubYSFlJz8sDxOKGkguhhW2-E#scrollTo=MAQo8wzlIdrx Here you can find the code. I have almost pasted and copied the oxford pets example, adding only my own UNet definition.

Comment: Make it public. I needed to send you a request.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think your answer will come in handy to many people. All the best.