# NotImplementedError: Layer DenseVariational has arguments in `__init__` and therefore must override `get_config`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to save my TensorFlow model using model.save(), however - I am getting this error.

The code for the BNN model:

```
bnn = tf.keras.Sequential(layers=[tfpl.DenseVariational(20,make_posterior_fn=posterior,make_prior_fn=prior,kl_weight= 1 / train_size,activation = activation, input_shape = (2,))]+ \
             [tfpl.DenseVariational(hidden_layer[i],make_posterior_fn=posterior,make_prior_fn=prior,kl_weight= 1 / train_size, activation = activation) for i in range(1, len(hidden_layer))] + \
           [tfpl.DenseVariational(1, make_posterior_fn=posterior,make_prior_fn=prior,kl_weight= 1 / train_size, activation = tf.keras.activations.softplus)],name="bnn")
#TRAINING
losses = []
print("START TRAINING")
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
for batch in range(n_batches):
    X_train, X_train_ = get_batch2(stock_path, batch_size) # get batch of theoretical options
    training_op(X_train.astype(np.float32), X_train_.astype(np.float32))
epoch_loss = loss(X_test.astype(np.float32), X_test_.astype(np.float32))
losses.append(epoch_loss)
print('Epoch:', epoch, 'Loss:', epoch_loss) #, 'BS Loss:', bs_hedging_mse.eval({X_input: X_test, X_input_: X_test_}))
bnn.save('model.h5')

plt.figure()
plt.semilogy(np.arange(n_epochs), losses)
plt.xlim([0, n_epochs])
plt.savefig('loss.png')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58678836/notimplementederror-layers-with-arguments-in-init-must-override-get-conf/58799021

Comment: Could you help me oveeride the get_congig for this specific case