# Layer ModuleWrapper has arguments in `__init__` and therefore must override `get_config`. in Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback

I'm trying to make keras modelcheckpoint code. But Whenever I started the code, that get_config error occured. Below is my keras code.

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(8,)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate =0.0001),
            loss = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(reduction="auto"),
            metrics = 'mae')


mc2 = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('best_model_scaled'+str(fold_no)+'.h5', 
monitor='val_loss', mode='min', save_best_only=True,verbose=1)
es=keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', patience=1500)
history = model.fit(x_train2, y_train2, batch_size=16,epochs=2000, validation_data = (x_val2, y_val2), callbacks = [es,mc2])
```

I saw other questions and found that "def get_config(self):" code solves the problem. But I have no "Class():" code for "get_config(self)".
Please help me solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using colab?

Comment: Also please add full imports to your question.

Comment: Yes. I use Colab.

Comment: I made my model by using Sequential().(this described above)
And I want to train this model by model.fit & callback
But whenever i save my model by ModelCheckpoint, "Layer ModuleWrapper has arguments in `__init__` and therefore must override `get_config`". occured
In my thought, something isn't renewed so that error occurs. But I can't find what it is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58678836/notimplementederror-layers-with-arguments-in-init-must-override-get-conf/58799021
In this page, he solved the problem by 
    def get_config(self):
    config = super().get_config().copy()
    return config
in def.
But I didn't define my model by def. If I have to define "def get_config", where is the location?

Comment: You still need to add all the imports to your question.

Comment: sorry but could you tell me what is "import" of the question?

Comment: The python statements you use to import libraries like keras in your code.

Comment: import tensorflow /
from tensorflow import keras /
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU /
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping /
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint /
I used these and keras version is 2.5.0

Comment: Dr.Snoopy. I found what is wrong. Maybe "from tensorflow import keras" is wrong. When I changed that code into just "import keras", it works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You were mixing imports between tf.keras and keras which is not supported

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by mixing imports between the `keras` and `tf.keras` libraries, which is not supported.

You should **never** mix imports between these libraries, as it will not work and produces all kinds of strange error messages. These errors change with versions of `keras` and `tensorflow`.