# Layer PositionalEncoding has arguments in `__init__` and therefore must override `get_config`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, huggingface-transformers

while saving model i use `model.save()` but it gave error
'''Layer PositionalEncoding has arguments in `__init__` and therefore must override `get_config`

````
  def __init__(self, position, d_model):
    super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
    self.pos_encoding = self.positional_encoding(position, d_model)

  def get_angles(self, position, i, d_model):
    angles = 1 / tf.pow(10000, (2 * (i // 2)) / tf.cast(d_model, tf.float32))
    return position * angles

  def positional_encoding(self, position, d_model):
    angle_rads = self.get_angles(
        position=tf.range(position, dtype=tf.float32)[:, tf.newaxis],
        i=tf.range(d_model, dtype=tf.float32)[tf.newaxis, :],
        d_model=d_model)
    # apply sin to even index in the array
    sines = tf.math.sin(angle_rads[:, 0::2])
    # apply cos to odd index in the array
    cosines = tf.math.cos(angle_rads[:, 1::2])

    pos_encoding = tf.concat([sines, cosines], axis=-1)
    pos_encoding = pos_encoding[tf.newaxis, ...]
    return tf.cast(pos_encoding, tf.float32)

  def call(self, inputs):
    return inputs + self.pos_encoding[:, :tf.shape(inputs)[1], :]


sample_pos_encoding = PositionalEncoding(50, 512)```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NotImplementedError: Layers with arguments in \`\_\_init\_\_\` must override \`get\_config\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58678836/notimplementederror-layers-with-arguments-in-init-must-override-get-conf)

Comment: thanks for your answer but link you provided does not worked for me

Comment: Could you elaborate on how it does not work for you?

Comment: The error is very clear, your Layer must override get_config, and it is not doing it, you need to include everything that you tried and did not work, and why it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks dear I had included every thing and now i m getting erroe that (AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'get_config')

Comment: i  had resolved this error thanks for giving me suggestion but i got new error which i posted seprately i am providing the link lindly have a look on that one.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68205450/attributeerror-super-object-has-no-attribute-get-config