# Model saving problem - NotImplementedError: Layer ModuleWrapper has arguments in `__init__` and therefore must override `get_config`

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to save my AI model but it shows the error

```
 NotImplementedError: Layer ModuleWrapper has arguments in `__init__` and therefore must override `get_config`.
```

I tried to find many sources to solve this problem, but I couldn't figure out how to apply code customized to my model. My model is about detecting diseases in plants by providing photos.
My code doesn't have a 'Class' for making the model so I couldn't find out where to add additional code for solving this problem.

Could anybody help me with it?

Below is my whole code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras import models, layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

IMAGE_SIZE = 256
BATCH_SIZE = 32
CHANNELS = 3
EPOCHS = 50
dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "D:/ml/training/PlantVillage",
    shuffle = True,
    image_size = (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE
)
class_names = dataset.class_names
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for image_batch, label_batch in dataset.take(1):
    for i in range(12):
        ax = plt.subplot(3,4,i+1)
        plt.imshow(image_batch[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
        plt.title(class_names[label_batch[i]])
        plt.axis("off")
len(dataset)
# 80% ==> training
# 20% ==> 10% validation, 10% test

train_size = 0.8
len(dataset)*train_size
train_ds = dataset.take(54) 
len(train_ds)
test_ds = dataset.skip(54)
len(test_ds)
val_size=0.1
len(dataset)*val_size
val_ds = test_ds.take(6)
len(val_ds)
test_ds = test_ds.skip(6)
len(test_ds)
def get_dataset_partitons_tf(ds, train_split=0.8, val_split=0.1, test_split=0.1, shuffle = True, shuffle_size = 10000):
    ds_size = len(ds)
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(shuffle_size, seed = 12)

    train_size = int(train_split * ds_size)
    val_size = int(val_split * ds_size)
    train_ds = ds.take(train_size)
    val_ds = ds.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
    test_ds = ds.skip(train_size).skip(val_size)
    return train_ds, val_ds, test_ds
train_ds, val_ds, test_ds = get_dataset_partitons_tf(dataset)
len(train_ds)
len(val_ds)
len(test_ds)
train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = test_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
resize_and_rescale = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1.0/255)
])
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"),
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2),
])
input_shape = (BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, CHANNELS)
n_classes = 3
class ResizeAndRescale(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ResizeAndRescale, self).__init__()

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.image.resize(inputs, (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))/255.0


class DataAugmentation(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DataAugmentation, self).__init__()

    def call(self, inputs):
        inputs = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(inputs)
        k = tf.random.uniform(shape=[], minval=0, maxval=4, dtype=tf.int32)
        inputs = tf.image.rot90(inputs, k=k)
        return inputs
        #return tf.image.random_flip_left_right(tf.image.random_rotation(inputs, 20))


model = models.Sequential([
    ResizeAndRescale(),
    DataAugmentation(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation = 'relu', input_shape = input_shape),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3,3), activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3,3), activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_classes, activation = 'softmax'),
])

model.build(input_shape=input_shape)

model.summary()
model.compile(
    optimizer = 'adam',
    loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
    metrics = ['accuracy']
)
history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=val_ds
)
model.evaluate(test_ds)
history
history.params
history.history.keys()
history.history['accuracy']
acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']

loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.plot(range(EPOCHS), acc, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(range(EPOCHS), val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.plot(range(EPOCHS), loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(range(EPOCHS), val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.show()
import numpy as np
for images_batch, labels_batch in test_ds.take(1):
    first_image = images_batch[1].numpy().astype('uint8')
    first_label = labels_batch[1].numpy()
    print('first image to predict')
    plt.imshow(first_image)
    print("actual label:", class_names[first_label])

    batch_prediction = model.predict(images_batch)
    print("predicted label:", class_names[np.argmax(batch_prediction[1])])
def predict(model, img):
    img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(images[i].numpy())
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)

    predictions = model.predict(img_array)

    predicted_class = class_names[np.argmax(predictions[0])]
    confidence = round(100 * (np.max(predictions[0])), 2)
    return predicted_class, confidence
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
for images, labels in test_ds.take(1):
    for i in range(9):
        ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
        
        predicted_class, confidence = predict(model, images[i].numpy())
        actual_class = class_names[labels[i]] 
        
        plt.title(f"Actual: {actual_class},\n Predicted: {predicted_class}.\n Confidence: {confidence}%")
        
        plt.axis("off")

import os
basic_version = max([int(i) for i in os.listdir("D:/ml/models") + [0]]) + 1
model.save(f"D:/ml/models/{basic_version}")
model.save("basic.h5")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NotImplementedError: Layers with arguments in \`\_\_init\_\_\` must override \`get\_config\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58678836/notimplementederror-layers-with-arguments-in-init-must-override-get-conf)